# Rails Git Migration Issue With Branches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, cloud9, dbmigrate

Still a newbie. I'm working on a new feature for a RoR app. I created a local branch and generated a migration. Unfortunately I didn't save my changes to the migration file and then ran db:migrate. Wanting to start over, I switched back to master and repulled from my git and did a hard reset with the following commands (I never committed the files in the branch either locally or remotely):

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

I then remade a local branch, recreated the migration (correctly this time) and ran db:migrate. I get an error that the table already exists in the database, however, when I look in schema.db the table isn't there.

All I want is to go back to where I was based on the remote git. For what it's worth, I'm using Cloud9 on AWS for development. Thanks!

Comment: just delete wrong table, and updated migration will create correct table.

Comment: Does the migration file still exist in your local machine?
any add column logs generated while running rake db:migrate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing to do with database when you make changes regarding git. Once you run rake task like `rake db:migrate` to make database changes, it will get reverted automatically once you change branch, You have to prepare rollback steps. (As down methods in migrations are run conventionally)

Your old migration version was different than new recreated migration so application tried to run migration file without checking whether table exists.

Whenever you run `rake db:migrate` in for particular database, it store migration version in your `schema_migrations` table in db. So calling again and again same rake will not try to create table with same name. In above case you have different migration files to create same table and `schema_migration` table do not know whether you deleted branch with old migration file or whether table already exists

So run following in your rails console,

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table :table_name
```

And then run your `rake db:migrate`